# Extracting Text/Parameter *within* a Tag

Tags: xml, select, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I have the following source code from which I am attempting to extract my desired information:

```
<div id="PaginationBottom" class="pagination">
    <a href="#" data-page="2" title="page 2 of 31" >2</a>
    <a href="#" data-page="3" title="page 3 of 31" >3</a>
    <a href="#" data-page="4" title="page 4 of 31" >4</a>
    <a href="#" data-page="10" title="page 10 of 31" >10</a>
    <a href="#" data-page="2" title="page 2 of 31" class="next" >next &raquo;</a>
</div>
```

What I want to extract is the `title="page 2 of 31"` information ***from within*** the final tag itself.  I can get the tag with the following code:

```
response.xpath('//div[@id="PaginationBottom"]//a[@class="next"]').extract()
```

Thus, what I'd like to know is whether it is possible to extract a parameter's text from within the tag itself.  Is it?  I can't find information on this anywhere, but I'm brand new to xpath and don't know the best search terms.  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `/@title` to the end of your xpath expression:

```
//div[@id="PaginationBottom"]//a[@class="next"]/@title
```

Demo from the [`scrapy shell`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html):

```
>>> response.xpath('//div[@id="PaginationBottom"]//a[@class="next"]/@title').extract()
[u'page 2 of 31']
```

---

Just a follow up. You would probably want to get the maximum number of pages from the `title` attribute value, `31` out of the `page 2 of 31`. Scrapy Selector's built-in [`re()`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#scrapy.selector.Selector.re) method would be helpful here:

```
>>> response.xpath('//div[@id="PaginationBottom"]/a[@class="next"]/@title').re('page \d+ of (\d+)')
[u'31']
```

Comment: what text editor or IDE do you use with `scrapy shell`?  that is what I'm using, yes, but I haven't yet experimented with scrapy's test environment.

Comment: @BeeSmears I'm just doing it on the console. I've saved your html to the `index.html` file (also added closing `div` to make it valid), then started `scrapy shell index.html` and that's it. You would have `response` variable available right away. It is basically the same as being inside the `parse()` callback. Pretty good for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Try a simple one like this:(htmltext is the text you want to parse)

```
regex1 =  '<a href="#" data-page="2"(.+?)>2</a>'
pattern1 = re.compile(regex1)
Extracted_Text = re.findall(pattern1,htmltext)
print Extracted_Text
```

This code extracts everything between `<a href="#" data-page="2"` and `>2</a>`
Output would be like: 
title="page 2 of 31" and so...